# Excel: Array formula returning unexpected result

Tags: arrays, excel, excel-formula

I have the formula:

```
=IF(C2=$C$1:C2,1,0)
```

which returns the value 1 (I believe this is correct as C2 will find a match with C2). My problem is that if I turn this into an array formula

```
{=IF(C2=$C$1:C2,1,0)}
```

this returns a value of 0, however I am not sure why.

Could someone provide an explanation on the different results from each formula?

Comment: what are you trying to achieve - to me neither of your formulae return any useful information... remember that `{=IF(C2=$C$1:C2,1,0)}` will return an ARRAY, so if other cells are filled in it is possible you are seeing only the first result from an array.

Comment: In the first instance, is C1=C2?

Answer (score 1):

In the non-array version, the fact that you are passing an array of cells to the IF function is redundant, since, without array-coercion, the array resolves to just the first cell within that array, i.e. C1, so effectively the (non-array) construction:

=IF(C2=$C$1:C2,1,0)

is identical to simply:

=IF(C2=$C$1,1,0)

In the array version, a 1 will only be returned if the values in **both** C1 and C2 are equal to the value in C1 (though of course this is a little redundant in itself, since the value in C1 will always be equal to itself!).

What exactly are you trying to do with this odd-looking construction?

Regards